# How to disable the Finish button on a Wicket DynamicWizardStep?

Tags: java, wicket

I am using a Wicket DynamicWizardStep (wicket extensions), which presents a number of navigation buttons (Prev, Next, Cancel, Finish)

On my last wizard step I need to disable the 'Finish' button if certain conditions are not met.

The DynamicWizardStep can implement certain methods to control the behaviour of the buttons, but it's not clear to me if it's possible, or what conditions need to be met for the Finish button to be disabled. At the moment I've implemented the following methods, because this particular step is the last one in my wizard.

Is there a way of selectively enabling/disabling the Finish button?

```
@Override
public boolean isNextAvailable() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public IDynamicWizardStep next() {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is to implement

```
@Override
public boolean isLastStep() {
    return false;
}
```